# How to implement setEncoding in my own Node.JS readable Stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

In my program, I have a readable `Stream` `source` which emits data events from a shared stream of byte data. I then interpret the data to extract `Buffer` objects, and then pass them to the appropriate function. The most elegant way of passing the `Buffer`s to the rest of my program seems to be using a readable `Stream` object. That way my functions can read the stream the same way as if it were standalone stream.

Here is my current code:

```
var stream = new stream.Stream()
stream.readable = true
stream.pause = function () {
    source.pause()
}
stream.resume = function () {
    source.resume()
}
stream.readable = true
// in a loop, read the data from source stream, dissect the parts we want,
// and emit Buffer objects to the stream's data event.
```

How can I implement `setEncoding`?

<strike>Edit: I think the answer is related to this line in [the stream.js source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L28)</strike>

```
Stream.Readable = require('_stream_readable');
```

Furthermore, the correct answer may be to

- replace `new stream.Stream` with `new stream.Readable` and to
- replace `stream.emit('data', buffer)` with
  either `stream.onread(buffer)` or `stream.push(buffer)`. The thing is, I don't know which one.

Edit: `stream.Readable` is not available in version 0.8. It is available in 0.9 beta, and will be avilable in v0.10 stable when that comes out. The ideal answer to this question will describe both the 0.8- solution and the 0.9+ solution.

Answer (score 0):

use streams2. for 0.8, there's: https://github.com/isaacs/readable-stream